# What is the difference between REST API testing for HTTP and for HTTPS. What additional things needed to test HTTPS with RESTassured testing

Tags: api, rest, rest-assured, azure-automation, rest-assured-jsonpath

From comment part:

> I saw in code base that someone has used
> given().relaxedHTTPSValidation() method. I don't understand what this
> method does and what are the other additional things we need to pass
> in header for HTTPS protocol.

I want to know what are the additional things required while testing REST API request and responses on HTTPS protocol using RESTAssured java library? Please suggest.

Comment: What is your actual goal / what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I am new to API testing. I want to automate the tests which validates request and response of a get and post  REST API over https protocol. I am using RESTAssured java library for this. I saw in code base that someone has used given().relaxedHTTPSValidation() method. I don't understand what this method does and what are the other additional things we need to pass in header for HTTPS protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say:

You are using RestAssured to communicate to you application in HTTPS protocol, but you can't connect because `the certificate chain is not trusted`, means `SSL certificate is invalid`

To overcome it, you have 2 options:

- import a certificate into an SSL truststore then connect
- trust all hosts regardless the SSL certificate is invalid

The second option is convenient and suitable for dev and testing purposes, a lot of people often use it. It is method `relaxedHTTPSValidation()` in RestAssured.

You can read more: [here](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/blob/4eeb3d82b1d4672787b57ca45167a63085c8c1f1/rest-assured/src/main/java/io/restassured/config/SSLConfig.java#L255).